# MoveIt demo.launch error

Tags: ros, moveit, move-group

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I have used the setup assistant of MoveIt to create the config package and it worked fine. But when I launched the demo.launch file, I got the following error :

```
...
auto-starting new master
process[master]: started with pid [43949]
ROS_MASTER_URI=http://localhost:11311

setting /run_id to eb76e8ea-711b-11e6-8339-480fcf447f3c
process[rosout-1]: started with pid [43963]
started core service [/rosout]
process[joint_state_publisher-2]: started with pid [43980]
process[robot_state_publisher-3]: started with pid [43981] 
ERROR: cannot launch node of type [moveit_ros_move_group/move_group]: can't locate node [move_group] in package
[moveit_ros_move_group]
process[rviz_ipt_d_0342_43937_3307353756922455826-5]: started with pid [43982]
[ WARN] [1472827541.765044325]: The root link base_link has an inertia specified in the URDF, but KDL does not     
support a root link with an inertia.  As a workaround, you can add an extra dummy link to your URDF.
```

The URDF works perfectly fine with RViZ and Joint State Publisher GUI sliders (without MoveIt)  and after a while I get the interactive markers in RViZ (with MoveIt) and I am able to move the arm around but it says 'No Planning Library Loaded'. Also system dependencies seem to be satisfied. I'm unable to find out what the exact issue is.

**EDIT** :

I did binary installation of the MoveIt for Jade. I used [this](http://moveit.ros.org/install/) link to install MoveIt. Then I launched the setup assistant and created the config package following [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=asg-thB3mwA) video.

Here are the screenshots of RViz and Terminal after launching demo.launch :

[image: image description]

[image: image description]

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/243002/moveit-demo.launch-error/) by [bhavyadoshi26](https://answers.ros.org/users/26692/bhavyadoshi26/) on ROS Answers with karma: 95 on 2016-09-02

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-09-03**:
If this is the output right after you've used the Setup Assistant (ie: you haven't changed anything in the generated launch files), could you please report this at the MoveIt [issue tracker](https://github.com/ros-planning/moveit/issues)? Please mention how you installed MoveIt, and what happened.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-09-05**:
Issue: [ros-planning/moveit#200](https://github.com/ros-planning/moveit/issues/200).

**Comment by [bhavyadoshi26](https://answers.ros.org/users/26692/bhavyadoshi26/) on 2016-09-05**:
@gvdhoorn I have reported this issue to the MoveIt Issue Tracker. I have mentioned there about the steps that I followed. I'll edit the question here as well.

**Comment by [Ayush Sharma](https://answers.ros.org/users/28428/ayush-sharma/) on 2017-03-04**:
I am facing similar error. Can anyone help me?

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-03-04**:
No. Not without more information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The referenced ticket is already closed. If you still see the issue please take an action in [this post](https://github.com/ros-planning/moveit/issues/200#issuecomment-291085888).

---

Originally posted by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) with karma: 10937 on 2017-04-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0